# Javascript library to manage hierarchichal or tree data

Tags: tree

Is there a JavaScript library that can do the following on [hierarchical or tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))  data?

1. Make a clone / immutable copy of the tree?
2. Traverse the tree to locate a node.
3. Prune the sub-tree of a node.
4. Merge two trees that have  common node.
5. Insert or delete a node.

Comment: can you explain the actual application? [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/OrderedSet) might be sufficient

Comment: It's similar to a tree menu. There are categories and the products for those categories which is shown like a tree menu.

Comment: Try [tree-node-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-node-data) and [tree-node-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tree-node-utils), I am the author.